Create an atlas for each polygon in diferent time interval
I need a create an atlas were each polygon have various dates. For exemplo atlas of properties each properties in January, February, March, and April.
I know if I copy the same polygon of properties for each month and add a column with each month I can create an atlas with name of each propreties + date value. But sadly I have so big interval number how to do this without copy and paste?
I know I can create new page for each month and in each page sething temporal interval, sadly the number of interval is big.
I think join attributes for field value, where the type of join is one for many is the best way, I expect create each properties in month, but sadly no success.

Can you please add two or three lines of your attribute table as text? It is not entirely clear to me how your data is structutred.
